# How do I put a placeholder code into a form field in using Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, placeholder

I am trying to find a Rails-way of putting a simple placeholder into a form I have made for a contact page. The code is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= label_tag(:email, "email") %>
<%= email_field(:user, :address) %>
</div>
```

Where would I put placeholder code, and how would I do it in this context. I want it to say "ex: joe@joe.com" in the field until it is clicked on.

I am using Ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0], and Rails 4.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd put the `placeholder` in your email input.

[`email_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-email_field) returns a [`text_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field) of type email, so appending the placeholder attribute to the end of the parameter list in your `email_field` helper call should produce the expected result:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag(:email, "email") %>
  <%= email_field(:user, :address, placeholder: 'ex: joe@joe.com') %>
</div>
```

Comment: This placeholder option won't support in IE browsers.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= label_tag :email => "email" %>
<%= email_field :user, :address, :placeholder => "ex: joe@joe.com" %>
</div>
```